# Disable HTML5 video auto-play in OS X Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, video

I want to disable videos in Safari, as I have to pay for each byte downloaded.  Some videos I may want to watch, but *I* want to decide whether I use my precious bandwidth, rather than have it automatically play.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: For Flash, there's 'ClickToFlash' from the Apple Extensions Gallery, but idk for HTLM5, sorry

Comment: @Tetsujin no Flash installed on any of my machines.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to do that yet. I would install flash and then install click to flash. Then you can choose when to enable the video. It sounds like a good candidate for a plugin. The plugin would block all video tags.

Comment: For older versions of Safari, try ClickToPlugIn (by the maker of ClickToFlash) -- it would block the HTML5 player until you clicked on the player.  Alas, Safari 10 seems to have broken that ClickToPlugIn capability.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me (macOS Sierra 10.12.2, Safari 10.0.2), courtesy of jeffreyv in an [Apple Support thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7681448?start=0&tstart=0):

In the Terminal, enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1
```

That enables the Debug menu in Safari. Then tick this menu item on:

```
Debug -> Media Flags -> Video Needs User Action
```

Comment: I had high hopes for this @Fab.  I tested it out on Youtube.  After changing the setting, the video still downloaded into the buffer.  I also could not manually start it :-(

Comment: @PaulWaldo - oh :-(  Try some of the other settings, such as "Disallow Inline Video"? Really a bit pathetic that there's not a simple setting or even extension to turn off these damn things....

Answer (score 0):

It appears to currently not be possible to do this in Safari. While a plugin could exist to do this, I'm currently unaware of any.

[This](http://www.howtogeek.com/227669/how-to-stop-auto-playing-html5-videos-in-your-web-browser/) article does a good job summarizing the other options you have (other browsers). Of the list, I'd choose Firefox as it supports what you're looking for natively, though there are extensions/plugins for Chrome and Opera.

It may also be important to note that these only look for the `<video>` and `<audio>` tags. Other forms of media (big gifs, Java extensions etc.) which consume significant bandwidth may be able to slip through.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @agentroadkill.  Unfortunately, none of these will help my problem of anemic data allotment.  From the referenced link:  "Disabling automatic playback just pauses the video; it doesn’t prevent it from loading. ...
In other words, if you’d like to use this trick to save bandwidth, it won’t help much."

Answer (score 0):

I have had a little (but not enough) luck adding the following to my /etc/hosts file:

```
## Autoplay videos
127.0.0.1  vp.nyt.com
127.0.0.1  nythlslive-i.akamaihd.net
127.0.0.1  ondemand.abcnews.com
127.0.0.1  newsy-limelightovp3.creatorcloud.netdna-cdn.com
127.0.0.1  player.hearstdigitalstudios.com
127.0.0.1  c.brightcove.com #Independent
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Disable extensions in Develop Menu